# How do I show a view of documents for the current user's department?

Tags: document-library, filter, security-trimming

My first sharepoint task ever is to create a demo document management site, i need to define a way of departmentalising documents added to the store, then when a user logs in they only see documents by their department. How is best to do this, i don't know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use different scenarios :

- Apply security on a series of list depending on the AD Group they are in
- Apply "By Item" security on a single list by adding an event handler by code, and with some logic, apply the good group to the item
- Adding a column that would be the department, and filter the list by that column
- Using this solution to edit the regular view http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/9dfce274-02d9-4232-80c0-8139a94e96ea/

There's a lot of options, it depends of your level of comfort with code and with the platform.

Comment: Currently looking for the quickest and most straight forward, spent the last 12 months doing support work and not touched code, or sharepoint yet. I have done a little C# before but nothing major. It has been the typical we want this, and wanted it yesterday to demo to clients scenario :)

Comment: You probably need code to fill those requirements... The simplest would be the third option, but you won't have any real security, only filtered view...

You can look at some third party solution... I already tested that one (http://www.titus.com/software/sharepoint/metadata.php) and it is a good solution, you can establish some logic to establish real "By Item" security depending on some Metadata.  Maybe it is more what you could get the most without code.

Comment: What i need is that 3rd option, which is ideally simple but with it filtering by the department of the user that has logged in at the time. I have done a little C# where i have grabbed data from active directory, which is i imagine what i will need to do here too using LDAP. Security isn't an issue as it is merely for demo purposes used by the sales guys. I may even resort to mimiking the results i need by creating user's with default filters added, if that possible and it gets desperate?

Comment: Do you want a security solution, or a display solution? I mean, do you want a solution that secures the items scoping them to a certain group, of only showing them to the good group, without concern about the item security ?

Comment: After the heat i have had for it this morning, a display version. I can learn what i need to afterwards (fingers crossed anyway). I figure alot of my time will be spent sat with sharepoint books for a while, lots to learn :)

Comment: Then you could add a metadata column representing the departments, then create some views filtered by department. That could do it!